# Add Javascript client to group without creating a Hub method

Tags: .net, signalr

All the examples I've found use a special Hub method to add a client to a group. Like this:

```
public class ProductsHub : Hub
{
    public void JoinGroup(string groupName)
    { 
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }
}
```

It makes sense if I want to implemenet some custom logic when a new client is Joined (e. g. notify other clients in the group). But is there a way to add a Javascript client to a group without creating a Hub method in case you don't need any custom logic. Something like this:

```
myHub.Groups.Join("groupName");
```

instead of

```
myHub.server.joinGroup("groupName");
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no shortcut to access Groups directly from a JS client.
Groups are managed by the server, so you need to notify the server in any case. You could customize SignalR to work the way you describe, but it seems like that would be much more trouble than keeping a 3-line method in your hub.

For the client, you could simply define a wrapper to get the syntax you want:

```
myHub.Groups = {
    Join: function() {
        return myHub.server.joinGroup("groupName");
    }
};
```